# How to fix Angular prod issue "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #321"

Tags: reactjs, angular, production, fuse

I have this error below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjHTg.png) when I am on the production. The app is built using fuse template

this is my package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.11",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-option-highlight": "^0.0.7",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "4.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^5.0.3",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "3.8.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^14.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "17.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "8.1.2",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.16.1",
    "angular-barcode-listener": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.28.16",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.11.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "d3": "5.16.0",
    "date-fns": "2.15.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.16",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-http-loader": "8.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.3.2",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.3.0",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "ngx-color-picker": "9.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "3.1.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "utils-decorators": "^2.0.4",
    "written-number": "^0.11.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "12.12.6",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1"
  },
```

I found that there is a library built with react that may cause this bug but I don't know which library can cause this bug

Comment: Please consider reformatting your question, you should put the exception in code brackets for readability

Comment: Do you have the chrome extension Loom installed? Please see this post https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/react-error-coming-from-shopify-minified-react-error-321/td-p/1965997